# iMac Pro Bootcamp: Two Thunderbolt ports not working, two are working correctly

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu, boot-camp, thunderbolt

I had my Bootcamp drive running a few weeks now great. an eGPU Connected to one TB Bus and my external NVMe with Windows on the other TB Bus of the iMac Pro. Runs great. Then I wanted to install bluetooth driver which were (strange) not installed and messed up the whole thing with "driver booster". After that TB ports are not working from one TB Bus.

I tried in safe mode to get the older drivers back of the TB devices in device manager but this did not really work.

After hours of getting it working again I just reinstalled Windows but the problem is still present. But now the other TB Bus is not working. (TB Bus is for me the Two-Pair of TB Ports which are PCIe connected) like displayed in macOS system informations.

In macOS all the ports work well.

**Status quo**

I can boot in windows by using the working TB Bus (no matter which of the two ports). When sticking my eGPU in the same TB Bus in the other port it won't boot (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE). When plug the eGPU in the other TB Bus nothing happens with the eGPU since the ports are not recognized.

When plugin the windows disk in the not recognized ports it starts booting but then (for sure) get blue screen (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE) when loading the "driver" or something – so within the boot screen and the initial boot process work these ports. But Windows is messing something up.

In device manager everything looks fine and installed. Installed for sure also bootcamp drivers and all windows updates.

How do I get that TB Bus running again? I also tried PRAM and SMC reset. Strange is that after this action after driver booster the system runs with the same problem but with the other TB Bus (exactly these ports which are not not running and vice versa).

Now I am trying to reinstall again. But it looks like the same from what I can see.

Oh and regular USB devices via USB 3 Hub works well. Only the eGPU / TB3 NVMe device do not work.

**Update**

I now plugged in the eGPU (Razer Core Chroma with 6800 XT) in running windows in the working TB Bus and it recognized the USB hub / Network / GPU – but do not display anything. And when trying to boot with disk and eGPU in same TB Bus the error above still persists.

**Update 2**

Now I saw the the driver in device manager is not marked with problem but in detail there is the apple driver installed with description "no driver installed". So I installed the intel Thunderbolt driver to the port that was not in use by the NVMe drive. And after that I restarted an could use my GPU on the second (always not working TB Bus). After a restart it fall back to previous not working state. Then I thought I start from USB in safe mode and install the intel TB driver on the other TB Bus, now I get always "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" – no matter what TB Bus/Port. So will now go back in safe mode to remove the drivers and install the Apple ones again.